# Scrape an image using Soup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lazy-loading

I am trying to scrape an image from this website: https://www.remax.ca/on/richmond-hill-real-estate/-2407--9201-yonge-st-wp_id268950754-lst. The current code is:

```
url = 'https://www.remax.ca/on/richmond-hill-real-estate/-2407--9201-yonge-st-wp_id268950754-lst'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), 'html.parser')
imgs = soup.findAll('div',  attrs = {'class': 'images is-flex flex-one has-flex-align-center has-flex-content-center'})
```

When I look inside of `imgs`, I cannot find the `image active ng-star-inserted ng-lazyloaded` and `srcset`. As the result, I cannot download the image.

Can someone suggest on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are lazy loaded and I think the problem is that. So I **scraped** the script that loads and manages these pictures.

```
script = soup.find('script', {'type': 'application/ld+json'})
script_json = json.loads(script.contents[0])
imgs = script_json['@graph'][1]['photo']['url']
```

Now `imgs` contains the list of all 11 images from the link you provided for that residence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath to find the image and use requests to obtain the image then write it to a file as follows

```py
import requests
from lxml import html

# send request to website
r = requests.get("thewebsite")

# convert to html object
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)

# find images urls from xpath
image_urls = tree.xpath("xpaths/@href")

# write each image to your computer 
for i in image_urls:
    with open("filename","wb") as f:
        f.write(i)
```

Comment: That didn't work. I cannot open `local_filename.jpg`